# How to make visual studio 2012 to show a hint about my functions on mouse over

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide, usability

Visual studio has a feature to show some info about a function when you hold a mouse cursor over a name of a function in the code editor window.

Is there a way to show some hint about some of my own functions not only about library functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - just comment your code with comments the places it expects and it should start showing them.

In the case of C++ code it expects a comment on the line above the function name in the .cpp file and/or the same in the .h file - *personally I would always try for both as humans can also use these comments and find them there!*

*Expansion:*

C++ Expects comments in C++ style i.e. `// Comment` **immediately** before the function declaration - you can continue over more lines if all start with `//`.  **N.B.** Other languages ***may*** differ.

Comment: Yes, it works. This is acceptable answer but still consider my edit or add some specifics. Because not every comment works. For example, comments like /* text */ will not work.

Comment: @av_lee I didn't get a chance to accept or reject your edit before it was voted out!